# Ubuntu could not connect to wifi

Tags: wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu on my machine. I was trying to connect my pc to my wifi network using correct security key. But I could not connect it, it repeatedly asked for authentication. But I made hotspot with my phone and then tried to connect the same Ubuntu machine to this wifi network. This time I was succesful. I can't find any reason. The interesting thing is I have windows7 installed on the same machine and when switch to Window then I can connect to the wifi right away. Thanks in advance ..

Comment: What's the brand/type of the WLAN card in it? Without this type of information it is very difficult to help. If you post the output of the command `lspci` we will be able to determine the brand/type of the wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

It happens for my mother's PC too.

Ubuntu (it must be said) has a poor driver support. Probably you're using an external Wi-Fi antenna, even worse.

You should try an Ethernet network connection to the modem (it must works)... when setup is terminated do immediately a **sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y** and reboot.

If you're encountering the same problem with Wi-Fi... hope to find online the proper driver or a workaround to support them.

Or wait for the 15.04.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I have reinstalled Ubuntu. The has been resolved now.